# Oracle APEX - Missing column in query when language changes

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

The application I'm working on can run on English or French. There is an interactive report that runs fine in English but when the app was ran in French an ORA error occurs saying that one of the columns isn't a valid identifier. When I went to check the debug logs, the resulting SQL when ran in French looks like an older version compared to the resulting SQL when ran in English.

```sql
--Original Source
   SELECT ...
      CASE
         WHEN (dependant_pkg.get_dependant_id (ee.memb_id, '0') IS NULL OR ee.re_enrolment_dt >= TRUNC (SYSDATE))
         and  (( SEC_USER_EXTERNAL_PKG.get_info_vc(:g_user_id,'entity_type_code') = 'AC' ) or not (:g_user_type = 'GR' and :g_brand_code = 'HB' ))
         THEN ... --codes
      END link,
      ee.empl_contact_email
  FROM empl_enrol ee, company c
 WHERE ...

--FRENCH
   SELECT ...
      CASE
         WHEN (dependant_pkg.get_dependant_id (ee.memb_id, '0') IS NULL OR ee.re_enrolment_dt >= TRUNC (SYSDATE))
         and not (:g_user_type = 'GR' and :g_brand_code = 'HB') --! missing/different condiition
         THEN ... --codes
      END link
         --missing column
      FROM empl_enrol ee, company c
      WHERE ...

--ENGLISH
   SELECT ...
      CASE
         WHEN (dependant_pkg.get_dependant_id (ee.memb_id, '0') IS NULL OR ee.re_enrolment_dt >= TRUNC (SYSDATE))
         and  (( SEC_USER_EXTERNAL_PKG.get_info_vc(:g_user_id,'entity_type_code') = 'AC' ) or not (:g_user_type = 'GR' and :g_brand_code = 'HB' ))
         THEN ... --codes
      END link,
      ee.empl_contact_email
      FROM empl_enrol ee, company c
      WHERE ...
```

Comment: SOLUTION: Reseed the translation application then republish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to actually post an answer so you could mark this solved.

Apex creates duplicate applications for different languages, thats why translations are mostly done after the app is completed. So you might just be changing the default app, but if you switch the language to french, it reverts to the older version.

You will need to republish the translated app.

Comment: Thanks! It needed a reseed before republishing.